# list Rails controller instance variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

i was trying to list the instance variables inside a controller but came up with

```
irb>HomeController.instance_variable_names
=> ["@visible_actions", "@inheritable_attributes", "@controller_path", "@action_methods", "@_process_action_callbacks"]
```

and I tried it on the action

```
irb>HomeController.action("index").instance_variable_names
=> []
```

so what do controller Instance variables belong to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The instance variables belong to the instantiated controller object, and are only created when the action method has executed. Try this:

```
irb>instantiated_controller = HomeController.new
irb>instantiated_controller.index
irb>instantiated_controller.instance_variable_names
=> ["@_status", "@_headers", ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also call `self.instance_variable_names` directly from the controller code and then see them in logs.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    logger.info("List of instance vars: #{self.instance_variable_names}")
    ...
  end
end
```