# Scan instance variable from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

Is there any way to read (scan) all the instance variables from the controller's methods?

ex:

I'll define some instance variables in a controller either index or show or custom defined method. I want to know (get) all the instance variable values from one place.

```
class TestClass
  def t1
    @v1 = "test"
  end

  def t2
    @v2 = "test1"
  end
end

TestClass.instance_variables
 => [] 

tc = TestClass.new
tc.t1
tc.instance_variable_names
=> ["@v1"]
```

The above code is working for the class with the custom methods not with default methods (index, show, etc..)

```
Rails.env
=> "development"
u = UsersController.new
 => #<UsersController:0x00000004233990 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil> 
1.9.3p448 :109 > u.index
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

call the instance_variables() method.

```
instance_variable_names()

# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables.rb, line 27
def instance_variable_names
   instance_variables.map { |var| var.to_s }
end
```

Comment: Is it working? I am sure it'll not work. Please put your answer with some example.

Comment: @Mr.Black i get it from the api doc. Not verify it by myself. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks. It's working only for the Class with custom methods not a resource methods. I got a duplication of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061489/list-rails-controller-instance-variables

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will probably be something like this:

```
a = TestClass.new
after_init = a.instance_variables
a.t1
after_t1 = after_init -  a.instance_variables
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not working with the Actual controller.

Comment: I have list of controllers which will have some unique variable across most of methods with different values. I need to get the value of the particular instance variable and pass to common function.

Comment: I suppose that you used in the controller 'before_action', call these methods manually before performing call 'index','show' ...

Comment: Yes, I thought also. But, seems I can't call the method index or show directly. See my updated question.

Comment: From the example it is clear only that you have some variable that does not have a method 'env'. Show the entire method code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55425/discussion-between-mr-black-and-vakiliy).